# Gradle Tooling : How to set environment variable

Tags: gradle, gradle-tooling-api

I have a custom plugin and I am writing tests to test it. For this I'm using gradle tooling api (I found that to be the recommended way to test).

One of the test requires me to run a task by setting some environment variable. How do I test this. I do not see `ProjectConnection` providing a way to set environment variable.

If I have to manually test I would have to do this :

```
setenv LRG_REPOS foo
gradle verify_lrg -PlrgName=abc
```

where `verify_lrg` is task added by my custom plugin.

Currently to solve this, I am running using `ProcessBuilder`, but would like to know if there is any gradle tooling way (because all other tests are using gradle tooling api)

Comment: What you pass is not an environment variable but a *project property*. It can be probably passed with `withArguments` method defined on `ProjectConnection` class.

Comment: No.it is environment variable LRGREPOS; I am already passing project property using withArguments

Comment: No idea then. Just have tried to set it up but it seems impossible for now.

Comment: Oh. Do you see this as valid enhancement to tooling api?

Comment: Yes, why not? Why you asking?

Comment: Oh great. Can I work on this enhancement ? What is the process to contribute (This will be my first opensource contribution, so pls bear if I'm asking something trivial). Thanks

Comment: Could you please join this room to continue the discussion: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81107/gradle-tooling-how-to-set-environment-variable ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be possible to configure environment variables via gradle tooling api since 3.5 version, see details at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/1029
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/446468213543e32a0ce1bce0bbedabcfe925c572/subprojects/tooling-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/tooling/LongRunningOperation.java#L190